# Log for unexpected shutdown

Tags: power-management, reboot, log

I have a computer with ubuntu 18.04 which has access to the public network and it is always powered since I remotely connect to it to check the status of some devices.

Sometimes, i find it powered off and I can't understand why this happens.
I disabled all the automatic updates and I have no active options that can automatically shutdown the system.

I thought to a power loss problem but I enabled the power on system option in the bios and it works because I tested it.

Is there a log file which I can check to understand why it shuts down?

Comment: If the hardware shuts the machine down, only hardware logs will provide details (hardware logs are box specific and only on specific servers; eg. temperature etc, and won't help if it was power loss anyway). On the system I'd look in `journalctl` for clues, if the OS wasn't involved in shutdown you should detect that because journal will just end (no clues is your clue), comparing with normal message you'd expect for shutdown/reboot.

Answer (score 5):

Use `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` to see the end of the previous boot's log.